# Database .dat file open

Tags: sql-server, database, excel

I have my client database from which i need to import data to ms sql .

I dont have any idea how those .DAT files are created. I tried almost everything and unsucessfull. The only way which gives me some informations is if i open file with notepad. I can read some lines like this

```
 êÿÿÿÿSLOVENIJA                       xÿÿÿÿSRBIJA                          ÿÿÿÿSVEDSKA
```

[image]

Also in those collection of dat files i found

Magic.ini - Configuration file

Seems like those files are created with some

> [MAGIC_ENV] Owner = Magic Software Enterprises Ltd

[image]

Anyone have any solution how to convert those data to SQL / ACCESS / EXCELL

Comment: You need to know what format those files are.

Comment: @SeanLange Unfortunately i can't get that information. This forum is only place i may find help otherwise i will need to quit

Comment: Do they have a front end?

Comment: **Magic Software Enterprises** is *a global enterprise software company headquartered in Or Yehuda, Israel. It is listed on the NASDAQ Global Select and is also listed on the Tel Aviv Stock Exchange TA-100 Index.*. Google could have told you that.

Comment: I guess you may have to quit then. We can't tell you what a file is. How can you say you have a client database when all you have is a file with a dat extension? That is NOT a database. It could be any number of file formats. Perhaps you know what DBMS was being used? You need to figure out how to restore that to something usable and then you can extract the data.